# OnCollisionEnter not working with duplicate of an object

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

So I have a wall where the player can jump on and it detect the collision and reduce the gravity. This is working fine.
**This is what it looks like**
[Mossy Wall (L)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6wUPZ.png)

and here is the code:

```
 private void OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D collision)
{
    if (collision.gameObject.CompareTag("MossWall"))
    {
        onMossyWall = true;
    }
}

private void OnCollisionExit2D(Collision2D collision)
{
    if (collision.gameObject.CompareTag("MossWall"))
    {
        onMossyWall = false;
    }
}
```

As you can see it's pretty basic, all I want is to set *onMossyWall* to true when there is a collision and it works perfectly for this one.
Now I want to do the same but for an opposite wall, I copy the object (*Moss Walls (R)*), and rotate the platform effector so that it's on the opposite direction, and yet nothing happens. *onMossyWall* stay false. The tag is the same and the object is basically the same as the first one, why isn't this working ?
[Mossy Wall (R)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rd2zy.png)

I assume I must have forgotten something stupid but I have been looking for solutions for a while and I found nothing that works. I tried with a different tag but still nothing.

Comment: Hi, apart from the different tags on both pictures I can't see a difference (but you said you tried with different tags so I guess you tried with "MossyWall" on both of them). Have you tried to add a Debug.Log("Enter or Exit"); on CollisionEnter and Exit to troubleshoot instead of looking at the onMossyWalls value ?

Comment: You have one wall tagged `MossWall` the other one is tagged `MossWall_L` ...

Comment: The different tags was just a way to try another way to see if it would work and I forgot to make them the same on the screenshot but that's not the issue. Even if I make them the same only the left wall detect collisions. Yes I tried the Debug.Log and still nothing

Comment: please use the correct tags ... [`unityscript`](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/unityscript/info) is or better **was** a JavaScript flavor like custom language used in early Unity versions and is long deprecated by now ... your code is clearly `c#`

Answer (score -1):

As unity docs states:

> OnCollisionEnter is called when this collider/rigidbody has begun
> touching another rigidbody/collider.

So please make sure you have colliders on both objects and one of the object must have a rigidbody.

Comment: Yes the player has a collider and a rigidbody, and the walls have one too. Everything is working on the left wall and not on the right one which is almost an exact copy of the left one.

Comment: Did you debug log the collision enter event?